# Smoothing tame topological knots, from an analytic perspective

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, smoothing-theory

A tame topological knot (for the purpose of this question) is a topological embedding of $S^1 \times D^2$ into $\Bbb R^3$.

Tame topological knots are known to be isotopic to smooth knots.  This question aims to quantify "how far one must travel" to smooth the knot.

**Q:** Does a tame topological knot have an "almost" $C^\infty$ Seifert surface?

Here "almost $C^\infty$" Seifert surface means there is a compact, orientable topological $2$-manifold $\Sigma$ (with boundary) embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ such that its boundary is the image of $S^1 \times \{0\}$ under our embedding $S^1 \times D^2 \to \Bbb R^3$.  Moreover, the interior of $\Sigma$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$.

i.e. this is a strong manifestation of the statement that smooth knots are dense in tame topological knots.

I would guess the answer to this question is known, and I imagine it would have likely happened in the 60's through mid 70's, but I do not recall hearing a statement of this form.

For some context, Moise's paper "Affine structures in 3-manifolds" Theorem 6 says there is a homeomorphism of $\Bbb R^3$ supported in an arbitrarily small neighbourhood of the knot, which smooths the knot.  So by this theorem, there is a surface $\Sigma \subset \Bbb R^3$ whose boundary is the knot, and outside of a small neighbourhood of the knot, is smooth.   The issue is that we do not have any control over this surface as the neighbourhood varies, so there isn't a direct way to just take a limit.

I suppose one could really hit the problem over the head with the 3-manifold theory hammer, and argue that the smoothings of the knot are unique up to a small smooth isotopy, so that the smooth Seifert surfaces we can assume are nested (outside of the neighbourhoods).  This would allow for a limit process.

But I'm aiming for a more organic argument than this.   Perhaps there isn't one in the literature?

Comment: You can smoothen a given Seifert surface by convolution. If you make the function, you convolve with, dependent on the distance to the boundary, you get the result you want.

Comment: Certainly there are smoothing processes that involve convolution, but I do not see one available in this circumstance.   One of the main problems with convolution-type arguments is they tend to not preserve functions being embeddings.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that. So let's say you assume additionally, that your knot admits a diagram with finitely many crossings (maybe that's automatically true), but then I guess you can modify the usual process of constructing a Seifert surface in a way that you get a smooth surface outside an arbitrary small neighbourhood U of the knot. You can iterate this process to get ever closer to the knot and at the same time make the surfaces agree outside a somewhat bigger neighbourhood. That menas, they will converge to a Seifert surface which is smooth in the interior.

Comment: @Echo: okay I think I see how to assemble an argument using your sketch.  You really have to hit the problem over the head with a lot of 3-manifold theory.   But I think there is an argument there.  Unfortunately it's not the kind of organic argument I was hoping for.